# ImageButton not Showing

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to add an ImageButton at first, and here is the XML that contains it:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/name_search_layout"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/label_name"
        android:text="@string/name_label"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text_name"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_expand"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is inside another LinearLayout, but my button don't appear, it shows like this:

[image: The button is circulated in blue]

How can i make it appear?

Comment: can you implement Floating fab button? Here you have amny options: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/173

Comment: I could try, but I want the image button to be showed at the same line of the text view and edit view

Comment: first try to check if FAB is displayed ;-)

Comment: Same thing, it gets tiny on the preview

Comment: Where do you want it to be shown?

Comment: On the right of the editText

Comment: ok, I need full xml file to check it

Comment: EditText takes `match_parent` place, change to `wrap_content`. Consider to use `layout_weights`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your imageButton not show, because, the width of **EditText** is **match_parent**, please change it to **wrap_content** like this

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:id="@+id/name_search_layout"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/label_name"
    android:text="@string/name_label"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/text_name"
    android:hint="@string/name_hint"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button_expand"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus"
    />
```

Comment: It worked, also, before i tried rearring using the visual editor on Android Studio, somehow it worked as well

Comment: I think it would be better if you try with **RelativeLayout** , it easy to config position like : ***android:layout_alignParentRight="true"***, ***android:layout_toLeftOf***....

Comment: But how would be for the weight property? In my application, I change it in runtime